# databricks code to send filename and size to another table

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I have a code to check whether the incoming files had data or not.it checks for each of the files and performs the actions as mentioned in the code.
wanted to know how to send the file name, file size, and time at which that file was read to another table created using data bricks?

Comment: You have provided very little information, could you elaborate? What exactly is the file that you are trying to read? Is your file-reading code running in databricks? Where are the incoming files stored? What language is your file-reading code written in? Are simply asking how to insert a piece of information into a Databricks table? My assumption would be that if you have are already written some code that is running in Databricks then you would proficient enough to know how to insert data into a table so I'm confused as to what you are asking for.

Comment: Hi Michael, im trying to read json files. yes file-reading code is running in databricks.incoming files are coming from oracle. my file reading code is written in python. i had written a code which categories whether data is present in the json file or not. if the data is not present it will stop the process and email. but my ask here is ,i want to capture the filename , filesize and time at which the file was read and send it to the error table which im not able to figure out. and also im reading the files like one after the other, how to read it in micro batches?

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your code?

Answer (score 0):

When processing files with pyspark(Python) in Databricks you can loop over the files, process them one by one and as you process them create a dataframe that in the end you can save to a table.

```
columns = ['filename', 'size']
vals = [("example", 100000), ("example2", 100000)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(vals, columns)

for f in dbutils.fs.ls("/path"):

    # Process file ....

    newRow = spark.createDataFrame([(f.name, f.size)], columns)
    df = df.union(newRow)

df.write.format("parquet").mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("database.tablename")
```